# ConEmu / Cmder replaces Command Prompt without features

Tags: command-line, terminal

So, after using Console2 for a long time, I finally discovered Cmder (based on ConEmu). Epic terminal, but..

When I try to replace the default windows terminal with the settings, I go to settings and change to this:

[image]

Now, when I open my command prompt, it works, opens the terminal window, but not the fancy colored command filled version, but just the window with the plain old terminal version:

[image]

Here is the normal Cmder version, opened directly on the executable.

[image]

My question is: how can I make the replacement terminal also open with all the fancy colors, settings and commands? I tried all settings combination without success. :/

Comment: You run `cmd.exe`, without configuration, arguments or anything. **Why** do you think, that ConEmu shall apply the configuration from **Task** from ConEmu settings? Run `cmder` or `ConEmu` directly, I see absolutely no sense to run `cmd` itself.